# How to customise outer div when creating radioList in Yii framework 2?

Tags: php, yii2, radio-button

Below is my bootstrap activefield that generates radiolist.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'photo_id')->radioList(['A', 'B', 'C']) ?>
```

The above code generates the following HTML tags.

```
<div id="model-photo_id">
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="Model[photo_id]" value="0" checked=""> 
            A
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="Model[photo_id]" value="1" checked=""> 
            B
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="Model[photo_id]" value="2" checked=""> 
            C
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The target is `<div class="radio">`. I would like to customise this div by changing the class name or adding more class name, adding more attributes into this `div`, ect. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this custom template, instead of applying class to radio div, you can apply class to label also

```
echo $form->field($model, 'photo_id')
        ->radioList(
                [0 => 'A', 1 => 'B', 2 => 'C'], [
            'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {

                $return = '<label class="modal-radio">';
                $return .= '<input type="radio" name="' . $name . '" value="' . $value . '" tabindex="3">';
                $return .= '<i></i>';
                $return .= '<span>' . ucwords($label) . '</span>';
                $return .= '</label>';

                return $return;
            }
                ]
        )
        ->label(false);
```